# How to change field value of a node

Tags: 7, entities, hooks, theming

I have a field in a node where users entered data in an inconsistent format.  I need to parse that data (it's HTML) and re-format it so it looks correct.  Where is the best place to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to load a list of entity ID's.

2) Load the full entity using [entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7).

3) Optionally wrap the entity using [entity_metadata_wrapper](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7).

4) For each entity, manipulate the field to your desire then save the entity. If you have it in a wrapper use $entity_wrapper_object->save() or if using the entity it's [entity_save](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_save/7).

If you want to do this quickly and easily, install the devel module and use the PHP execute page @ example.com/devel/php. Go through each step and ensure you have the correct data to work with at each stage.

Optionally you could use something like [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to create a view and manipulate the data using a PHP field. This might be easier depending on your experience level.

[How to use EFQ](https://drupal.org/node/1343708)

Comment: These values are already saved.  How can I manipulate it on the fly?

Comment: How about hook_field_prepare_view()?

Comment: The values are not already saved, that's why the function is called 'presave' and the description states: "This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the database."

Comment: The values are saved, and exist in the entity (a commerce product entity).  They have been butchered, and there are too many of them.  So, I need to modify them pre-render to clean them up.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not being clear.  I know how to save the values to their corresponding entities.  What I'm trying to do is modify the markup, pre-render, on the fly.

Comment: That's going to depend on where the data is being displayed. Through a node template or a view you can use field and views-field templates respectively. If you want to alter the data everywhere it's loaded, you might want to look at something like hook_entity_load or hook_entity_view.

Comment: I think one of those two will do it.  Probably _load(), since I'll want the data to be formatted if loading an object programmatically.